# Is there a way to get the filename after using expand-archive function in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, unzip

I use the PowerShell function to unzip zip files. 90% of the time the zip filename is the same as the extracted filename replaced with the correct extension. However, sometimes the zip filename is completely different when extracted!

Of course I can use temp folders and get the file details etc. and then continue. However I was trying to figure out if the function provides the extracted filename.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try with `-PassThru`?

Comment: there doesn't seem to be a `-PassThru` parameter for the `Expand-Archive` cmdlet ... so you are likely stuck with using a temp dir OR switching to another compress/decompress util like 7zip.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey oh my they added `-PassThru` on PS Core, my bad. Yeah, def uncompressing on temp folder is best option.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - ooo! thank you for the heads up on ps7. [*grin*]

Answer (score 4):

```
Expand-Archive c:\temp\temp.zip -Verbose -Force *>&1  | % {
    if ($_.message -match "Created '(.*)'.*") {
        $Matches[1]
    }
}
```

If you want the FileInfo object of the created file

```
Expand-Archive c:\temp\temp.zip -Verbose -Force *>&1  | Foreach-Object {
    if ($_.message -match "Created '(.*)'.*") {
        Get-Item $Matches[1]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, this is working as per your answer. Greatly appreciated.